# Modifing select query to delete query

Tags: mysql

The following select query works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM JBPM_JOB job WHERE job.ACTION_ IN (SELECT ID_ from JBPM_ACTION WHERE ACTIONEXPRESSION_ LIKE '%#{reminderAction.addAsyncProcessReminder%warning%');
```

However, when I try to delete the rows retrieved here, it fails

```
DELETE FROM JBPM_JOB job WHERE job.ACTION_ IN (SELECT ID_ from JBPM_ACTION WHERE ACTIONEXPRESSION_ LIKE '%#{reminderAction.addAsyncProcessReminder%warning%');
```

What is wrong here?

The error message is:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'job WHERE job.ACTION_ IN (SELECT ID_ from JBPM_ACTION WHERE ACTIONEXPRESSION_ LI' at line 1`

Comment: Post error message if you faced any

Comment: Question updated with error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify you are deleting from the alias table, so use:

```
DELETE job FROM JBPM_JOB job WHERE job.ACTION_ IN (SELECT ID_ from JBPM_ACTION WHERE ACTIONEXPRESSION_ LIKE '%#{reminderAction.addAsyncProcessReminder%warning%');
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tested the query in sql server. works fine but there is possible that the values you are deleting have some relationship with other table like PK and FK.

if they have then you have to delete the records from those tables too..........

Comment: No this is not the case. Maybe this works in sql, but not mysql